# Is it possible to center align a number in a diamond?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center align this 1 in the diamond, but I can't figure out how to. Is this even possible? Please help...

```css
.num {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.num:after {
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div class="num">1</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use clip-path

```css
.num {
  background:pink;
  display:inline-flex;
  font-size:20px;
  width:80px;
  height:80px;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  clip-path:polygon(50% 0,100% 50%,50% 100%,0 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="num">1</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! This was really helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Or if you don't want to play with clips than you can use the following:

```
 <div class="num"><span>1</span></div>
```

CSS

```
.num {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: pink;
  position: relative;
  top: -15px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: center;
}

.num span {
  width: 20px !important;
  height: 40px !important;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -10px;
  vertical-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1
}

.num:after {
  text-align: center;
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -15px;
  top: 15px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 15px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: pink;
}
```

But be aware: this only works if you have fix sizes. If you use percentage, than you have to always calculate the margins/paddings.